How do I deploy Dagster on a server without Dockerizing?
I know that the recommended way to to deploy Dagster OSS is on a Docker container, or with multiple containers orchestrated with Kubernetes. However, this is not currently an option for me, and I would like to know what is the best way to deploy Dagster on an on-prem Linux server. Here are some of the key questions I would like to know:

How do I perform the actual deployment so that Dagster runs continuously on the server
How do I make it resilient so that it restarts automatically in the case of a server restart or crash
How should I configure my CI/CD so that I don't have to restart Dagster webserver each time I deploy new code, and instead I can just click the 'Reload all' button on the web page
How can I make the Dagster web server page easily accessible, so that I, or my teammates can access it from a local machine
What are some common pitfalls or issues that I should watch out for if I choose to deploy in this manner

So far, my makeshift solution has been to run this command:
setsid dagster dev >/path/to/log_file 2>&1 < /dev/null &
While it does keep the Dagster webserver running, it isn't very resilient and I just don't feel like it's a very elegant solution.
